# Specializing multiprocessing.Pool workers

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a list of items and several instances of the same service that can process those items. I'd like to launch a few processes where each worker is fixed to a specific instance of the service, but pulls items out of the same list as it becomes free to process them.

To take the first example from the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I'd like to modify it so that `f(x)` actually becomes (logically) more like:

```
def f(worker, x):
    return (f'processed on worker {worker}', x*x)
```

where `worker` is something I can use to fix to a specific service (e.g. as a key into the dictionary of services or something along those lines) in real life. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean when you say "is something I can use to fix to a specific service"?

Comment: @PieCot The above pool will have 5 workers. Say they are logically named `w1`, ..., `w5`. I'd like `w1` to always call instance 1 of the service, `w2` to always call instance 2 of the service and so on. I.e. worker `N` is always going to be fixed to service `N`.